# how to clear a variable using a timer

Tags: go

I have a golang script that whitelists IP's every time they pass a verification process.
I am wondering if there's a way to add a timer that clears that var maybe like every 30 minutes or hour?(golang)

`ipwhite            = []string{}`

Comment: You can do this by using a ticker https://gobyexample.com/tickers

Comment: I'd recommend posting a larger (but cut-down) example that shows how ipwhite is updated? What does your main loop look like? Depending on your code structure there are a couple ways to solve this. Eg, [`time.Timer`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Timer) and goroutines, or comparing against a [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) representing the last clear

Comment: ```   if valid {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "completed!")
    passedcaptcha++
    ipwhite = append(ipwhite, req.Header.Get("Cf-Connecting-Ip"))
    return
   }```

Comment: so whenever someone passes captcha it would add 1 to how many people passed captcha, then it would req the ip address and whitelist it. i want to keep passed captcha normal so it wont clear but would like to add a timer for 1 hour that would clear the ipwhite var everytime an hour passes.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP handlers are run concurrenty in separate goroutines. Hence it is critical you coordinate access to `ipWhite` to avoid race conditions. This can be done via [`sync.Mutex`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex) or channels.

There are 2 main approaches to handling expiry:

1. Starting a separate goroutine to expiry old entries. This requires extra coordination to start/stop goroutines/timers, etc.. and can be more complex.
2. Check for and handle expiry during add/lookup.

Here is a simple solution using (2):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ipWhite := NewExpirySet(3 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println(ipWhite.Lookup("1.1.1.1"))
    ipWhite.Add("1.1.1.1")
    ipWhite.Add("1.1.1.1")
    fmt.Println(ipWhite.Lookup("1.1.1.1"))
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(ipWhite.Lookup("1.1.1.1"))
}

type ExpirySet struct {
    timeout time.Duration

    mu         sync.Mutex
    items      map[string]entry
    nextExpire time.Time
}

func NewExpirySet(timeout time.Duration) *ExpirySet {
    return &ExpirySet{
        timeout: timeout,
        items:   make(map[string]entry),
    }
}

type entry struct {
    expiry time.Time
    count  int
}

func (s *ExpirySet) Add(v string) {
    s.lookup(v, true)
}

func (s *ExpirySet) Lookup(v string) int {
    return s.lookup(v, false)
}

func (s *ExpirySet) lookup(v string, update bool) int {
    now := time.Now()

    // All lookups/modifications must be done while the mutex is locked.
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()

    // Periodically check whether any entries need expiry by scanning
    // the entire map.
    if s.nextExpire.Before(now) {
        for k, e := range s.items {
            if e.expiry.Before(now) {
                delete(s.items, k)
            }
        }
        s.nextExpire = now.Add(s.timeout)
    }

    e, ok := s.items[v]
    // Always check whether the current entry needs to be expired.
    if ok && e.expiry.Before(now) {
        e = entry{}
    }

    if update {
        e.expiry = now.Add(s.timeout)
        e.count++
        s.items[v] = e
    }

    return e.count
}
```

An improved version would likely use a min-heap for the expiry and a separate goroutine to expire on demand, and potentially type parameters for Go1.18+ (exercise for the reader).

Outputs:

```
$ ./ipwhite 
0
2
0
```